# Jquery create text input element and append to form "field focus" does not work in Firefox -problem

Tags: jquery

I have the following code (see below) which makes the field focus on the inserted text input. But this does not work in Firefox. So I cannot type any text in Firefox.

```
$('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'test', name: 'test' }).appendTo('#form');
```

Is there any fix for this?

Thanks in advance!

--

**Correction to my question**

I found out that the problem is caused by

`$(selector).sortable().disableSelection()`

The only resolution I have now is to not call

`//disableSelection()`

Any other suggestions are more then welcome.

Comment: do you want to set the focus to the input box?

Comment: Text inputs do not focus also using jquery load('file.html #form')

Comment: I want to be able to type in the text field. If you can't focus you can't type either

Comment: well could you post on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why don't you try `$('#test').focus();` after your append statement?

Comment: I tried that too, it works when it is focused first time, but when I blur (click outside the field) and try to focus again then no result. This only happens in Firefox.

Comment: I have the same issue in firefox. I dynamically add rows to a table, which is kept sortable and it appears that I have to right-click the input fields in that table in order to give them focus. Worth noting that the 'handle' for sortable is the first cell, but these input fields are not in that cell.

Answer (score 2):

try for focus

```
$('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'test', name: 'test'}).appendTo('#form');

$('#test').focus(function(e) {
    alert('Focus');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code -

```
$('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'test', name: 'test', autofocus: 'true' }).appendTo('#form');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine with Firefox 45:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Javascript/jQuery Tests</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'test', name: 'test' }).appendTo('#myForm').focus();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post"></form>
</body>
</html>
```